# Fourier Transform of wave function

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

For a function $f(x)$ on $\mathbb{R}$, its Fourier Transform is given by

$$F(\xi) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{R} f(x)e^{-i \xi x}dx $$.

Then, what is the Fourier Transform of the wave function $f(x) = e^{i \xi x} $ itself? If I simply plug it in, I would get $\infty$. What does this mean?

Also, if $f(x) = e^{i \eta x}$, where $\eta \not = \xi$, what is its Fourier Transform?

Comment: $\delta(\xi-\eta)$

Comment: First, $f(x)$ should not depend on the transform variable $\xi$.  If $f(x)=e^{I\eta x}$ and $\eta \in \mathbb{R}$, then the Fourier transform of $f$ is $\delta(\eta -\xi)$ in terms of the Dirac Delta.

Answer (score 0):

first your definition of fourier transform is wrong.It should be : $$F(\zeta)=\int f(x)e^{-i\zeta x}dx $$ where f(x) is function of x only .By using fourier transform we are converting from x domain to $\zeta$ domain.
now for the second case the fourier transform will be : $2\pi\delta(\zeta-\eta)$